# Is it a prerequisite for the usage of the Gross-Pitaevskii equation, to assume a dilute Bose gas?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons

Is it a prerequisite for the usage of the [Gross-Pitaevskii equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation), to assume a dilute Bose gas? Or is it also for Bose-Einstein condensates which are not so dilute?